# Xcode Interface Builder - views are vertically ambiguous

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode5

Xcode is telling me that `8 views are vertically ambiguous`, but it's not pointing to which view controller in my storyboard is actually causing the problem. I've clicked the warning message which just takes me to the storyboard and tried expanding all 20 something view controllers in the document outline, and none are showing that little warning indicator.

[image]

How can I determine the offending view controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be a pretty ugly way of figuring out what views are causing the warnings but I was having the same problem. What I did was in the Issue Navigator, right click on the warning and click "reveal in log". In the log, xcode gave me the warning statements followed by a semicolon and a value. Then I opened the storyboard in TextEdit to see the XML of the storyboard. I searched the values and found that they were ID numbers for views in the storyboard. From there I was able to figure out what views in what view controllers caused the problems. Hope that helps.

Comment: That's a good idea for when the red/orange arrow won't show. Thanks!

Comment: I found that Xcode 5 wasn't showing me the IDs.  But I copied out the command line it was doing it and changed the --output-format flag to be xml1 and then I would get the list. Though even once I knew which views it was complaining about I can't figure out what is ambiguous about them.  Everything appears fixed to me.

Answer (score 7):

if you open the left panel on storyboard (Document Outline) you will see a red circle with arrow near the ambiguous view name. click it to see more details.

Here is an example with the red circle with arrow.

[image: Example of red circle with arrow]

Those details may include another such red circle with arrow that will make suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned I've tried looking through all view controllers in the Document Outline and none are showing that indicator.

Comment: No kidding? Apple´s suggestions are good for nothing, whoever implemented those error messages should be fired.

Comment: Clicking the red icon worked for me. Xcode7 even offered to "add missing constraints" and that cleared up my warnings.

Answer (score 2):

I got this silly issue, too. I selected all the elements, cut them, and pasted them again, then the warning disappeared. Really sucks.....

Comment: Were you working with a single view? I have about 25 views in this storyboard and am not sure where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting everything and turning auto layout  to off and then back to on, in the file inspector pane in the storyboard, solved it for me

Comment: Won't this wipe out all my constraints I have setup correctly everywhere else?